# Interacting with <dialog> with Geb/Selenium (only with Chrome)

Tags: html, google-chrome, selenium, spock, geb

All my Geb/Spock tests were running perfectly on Firefox and then I tried with Chrome (v59) and it keep hanging when an alert or confirm pop up is raised.

With Firefox I was using `withAlert{}` or `withConfirm{}` to handle those but it doesn't work with Chrome.

So I did some digging into views and I found out that dialog were managed by [this widget](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/). So I created accessors to `<dialog>` in my page object but Chrome is still unable to interact with it (no way to detect that the pop up is displayed nor closing it).
I tried several things such as using `displayed` or waiting for the text to be shown but nothing worked.

I am not used to jQuery so maybe I am missing something here?

Here is a sample of the code I must interact with:

```
<dialog class="qq-alert-dialog-selector">
    <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>

    <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
        <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">Close</button>
    </div>
</dialog>
```

And this is how I try to access to it (in my page object):

```
alertPopUp {$("dialog", class:"qq-alert-dialog-selector")}
alertCloseButton {alertPopUp.children("div.qq-dialog-buttons").children("button")}
```

And finally how I would like to test the pop up:

```
when: "Trying to upload ..."
uploadFileButton = incorrect.absolutePath

then: "An alerting pop up occurs"
waitFor{alertPopUp.displayed}


when: "Closing the pop up"
alertCloseButton.click(SubmitAClaim)

then: "Number of uploaded files should not change"
uploadedElements.size() == initialUploadedFiles
```

Can anyone help? I guess it may have something to do with chrome's *focus* (I mean if it is currently on the pop up or on the page behind.

**EDIT:**

After all, it seems that the problem is not linked with jQuery (good thing I guess). We can verify the dialog box is open thanks to [open attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_dialog_open.asp) in `<dialog>`. I have done something like this:

```
when: "Trying to upload ..."
uploadFileButton = incorrect.absolutePath

then: "A alerting pop up occurs"
waitFor {alertPopUp.getAttribute("open") == "true"}
```

But I still cannot interact with the dialog box: when I try to click on `alertCloseButton` it raise an `ElementNotVisibleException`. So it has something to do with browser focus, I guess.
I tried:

- `withWindow{}` or `driver.switchTo().window()` but the only window available is the main one.
- `withFrame()` but I get a `NoSuchFrameException`
- `driver.switchTo().alert()` but it raise a `NoAlertRaisedException`

So I wonder if someone know how Chrome considers `<dialog>` tag (alert, confirm, ...) ?

> Note: According to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=dialog), Chrome is the only browser compatible with `<dialog>` for now.

Comment: I managed to test if the pop up is displayed by using `waitFor{alertPopUp.getAttribute("open") != null}` it passes but I am not even sure it actually assert on the right thing. I still hang about clicking on the button in the dialog box. Selenium raise an `ElementNotVisibleException` and I've already checked: there are no several selected elements with one not visible. There is only one (`alertCloseButton.size() == 1`). Does anyone has an idea or do I log that as an issue on ChromeDriver 2.30?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally** I managed to find a way to handle this issue. I took a look into [google demo](https://demo.agektmr.com/dialog/) for `<dialog>` use and I used the [js object](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#js-object) provided by Geb to execute the js example from Google. This finally gives this:

```
when: "Trying to upload ..."
uploadFileButton = incorrect.absolutePath

then: "A alerting pop up occurs"
waitFor {alertPopUp.getAttribute("open") == "true"}


when: "Closing the pop up"
report "After upload"
js.exec """var dialog = document.querySelector(".qq-alert-dialog-selector");
    dialog.close();
    return true;
"""

then: "Number of uploaded files should not change"
uploadedElements.size() == initialUploadedFiles
```

This is *really* brute force and I don't like it as it relies a lot on back end, how dialogs are set up etc... But it works. I really hope Geb/Selenium will provide something easier to use (as `<dialog>`is W3C it will become usual on all browsers).